# How to pass innerText value of a div to a parent Component in React

Tags: reactjs, dom, react-hooks, react-props

Good day everyone,
I am having issues passing an innerText value to a parent component

Below is a screenshot for the parent component and the child component

**Parent Component which I want to receive the innerText value**
[image: Parent Component which I want to receive the innerText value]

```
       <input type="text" 
            value={value} 
            className='display_text'
            ref={outputRef}
            readOnly
       />
      <div className="flex">
      <PaperLetter sd={setValue}>teeth.</PaperLetter>
      <PaperLetter>brush</PaperLetter>
      <PaperLetter>my</PaperLetter>
      <PaperLetter>i</PaperLetter>
    </div>
```

**Child Component which I want to send the innerText value from**
[image: Child Component which I want to send the innerText value from]

```
export default function PaperLetter(props) {
   const [clicked, setclicked] = useState(false);
   const letterRef = useRef();


 const btnClicked =()=>{
//Change the className of the btn clicked to active
setclicked(true);
//Get the value of the letter btns clicked
const getValue = letterRef.current.innerText;
// How to pass this value to my parent component inorder to 
 update a state in the parent component is the major chanllege
 }

return (
    <p className={clicked ? 'letter clicked': 'letter'} 
       onClick={btnClicked} ref={letterRef} >{props.children}
    </p>
)
}
```

**state I want to update after receiving the value**
[image: state I want to update after receiving the value]

```
const [value, setValue] = useState('i brush')
```

Screenshoots are also available via the link for proper view

Comment: You are already passing setValue to child component. Are you getting any errors while calling props.setValue from child component?

Comment: Doesn't it have any performance effect on my application?

Comment: Yes passing functions as props can cause child to rerender sometimes. This applies if your parent component will render based on some other prop or state change. To avoid that you can use useCallback hook, so that the function will always have a reference value which wont change until component will be unmounted.

Comment: @J-007, Please can you help me check this out? https://assessmentquestion.netlify.app

Comment: I want if I click on the reset button so the output button can be set to the initial state and also the classNames for the button clicked as answers. Github: https://github.com/JoshuaOyewole/Nominis-assesment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Parent:**

```
const [text, setText] = useState('');



 const handleInnerText = (innerText) => {
        setText(innerText);
    }
       <input type="text" 
            value={value} 
            className='display_text'
            ref={outputRef}
            readOnly
       />
      <div className="flex">
      <PaperLetter handleInnerText={handleInnerText} sd={setValue}>teeth.</PaperLetter>
      <PaperLetter>brush</PaperLetter>
      <PaperLetter>my</PaperLetter>
      <PaperLetter>i</PaperLetter>
    </div>
```

**Child:**

```
export default function PaperLetter(props) {
   const [clicked, setclicked] = useState(false);
   const letterRef = useRef();


 const btnClicked =()=>{
   //Change the className of the btn clicked to active
   setclicked(true);
   //Get the value of the letter btns clicked
   const getValue = letterRef.current.innerText;
   // How to pass this value to my parent component inorder to 
   update a state in the parent component is the major chanllege
   props.handleInnerText(getValue);
 }

 return (
    <p className={clicked ? 'letter clicked': 'letter'} 
       onClick={btnClicked} ref={letterRef} >{props.children}
    </p>
 )
}
```

Now **innerText** will be saved in your parent comp variable as : text

Comment: Thanks, it's working fine. but I need help in making the resetBtn to reset the active classes from the button when clicked. Currently, the resetBtn is only resetting the output field.

Comment: Could you give me more info about what do you want to reset?